# How to look at slow query logs for aurora serverless

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have created aws aurora mysql with serverless option. For parameter group I have set

```
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /rdsdbdata/log/slowquery/mysql-slowquery.log
log_output = TABLE
```

When I connect to the instance and run `show global variables like '%log_out%';` it show the setting for log_out = FILE
Also I do not see any option like in instance type where I can set the log to show up in cloudwatch.

So How can I look at the slow query log for AWS Aurora Serverless

Comment: To assist with - How can I look at the slow query log for AWS Aurora Serverless - look at this URL please.  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-aurora-mysql-logs-cloudwatch/

Comment: there is no "Log exports" section in aurora serveless

Answer (score 0):

In your AWS parameter group, make log_output = FILE rather than TABLE.  This is a dynamic parameter and should cause your slow_query_log_file to include information for queries that take longer than 'long_query_time' seconds to complete execution.  Use SELECT @@long_query_time to determine current setting. long_query_time of 1 would probably be more useful than 10 (seconds).

Comment: I do not understand does aurora serverless not support TABLE? also if I change it to file How to I access the log file in aurora serverless.

Comment: As I understand the info in the URL above, your viewing opportunity is through Cloudwatch only.  After you cause them to be 'Published'.